# OpenCV findHomography and WarpPerspective not producing good results

Tags: opencv, homography, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I'm trying to use `FindHomography` to find the warp matrix between two cameras then stitch the images together using `warpPerspective`. However, the image-to-be-warped overextends and flips to the other side of the screen. Below is some simplified code to show the weird behavior:

```
vector<Point2f> obj, scene, objCorners, TransformedObjCorners;

scene.push_back(Point2f(324,21));
scene.push_back(Point2f(388,4));
scene.push_back(Point2f(392,110));
scene.push_back(Point2f(322,111));
obj.push_back(Point2f(21,18));
obj.push_back(Point2f(79,45));
obj.push_back(Point2f(76,128));
obj.push_back(Point2f(13,118));
objCorners.push_back(Point2f(0,0));
objCorners.push_back(Point2f(400,0));
objCorners.push_back(Point2f(400,300));
objCorners.push_back(Point2f(0,300));

cv::Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene);

perspectiveTransform(objCorners, TransformedObjCorners, H);
cout << "Transformed object corners are :" << endl;
cout << TransformedObjCorners << endl;
```

and my output is:

```
Transformed object corners are :
  [309.14066, 18.626106;
  -2.5252595, 298.53754;
   31.930698, 9.6980038;
   319.43829, 279.87805]
```

The coordinates are of the black box:

[image]

[image]

And you can see it abnormally warped here because of the negative coords:

[image]

I have been spending hours trying to track the problem. Any help/pointers in the write direction will be very helpful.
Thanks

**How to stitch the left image?**
if I'm stitching three images together, what will be the best approach? So I'm trying the left and the middle, and below is my result but is very weak:

[image]

Comment: what's wrong with that image? the transformation matrix is ok. The only problem I see is, that the camera movement doesn't give you perfectly homography-relation between the images. And if you try to patch a 3D scene to a 2D plane you obviously get some distortions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used your code, adapted the point locations (because your images have a title-bar) and warped one of the images.

these are the input images with point locations:

[image]

[image]

this is the code

```
    int main()
{
    cv::Mat input1 = cv::imread("../inputData/panoA.png");
    cv::Mat input2 = cv::imread("../inputData/panoB.png");

    cv::Mat result;


    std::vector<cv::Point2f> obj, scene, objCorners, transformedObjCorners;

    std::vector<cv::Point2f> transObj, transScene;


    // had to adjust your coordinates since you provided images with title-bar
    scene.push_back(cv::Point2f(313,47));
    scene.push_back(cv::Point2f(379,21));
    scene.push_back(cv::Point2f(385,131));
    scene.push_back(cv::Point2f(317,136));
    obj.push_back(cv::Point2f(9,41));
    obj.push_back(cv::Point2f(70,61));
    obj.push_back(cv::Point2f(69,149));
    obj.push_back(cv::Point2f(7,145));
    objCorners.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,0));
    objCorners.push_back(cv::Point2f(input2.cols,0));
    objCorners.push_back(cv::Point2f(input2.cols,input2.rows));
    objCorners.push_back(cv::Point2f(0,input2.rows));

    cv::Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<scene.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::circle(input1, scene[i], 5, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));
    }

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<obj.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::circle(input2, obj[i], 5, cv::Scalar(0,255,0));
    }



    cv::Mat result1;
    cv::warpPerspective(input2, result1, H, cv::Size(input1.cols*2, input1.rows));

    cv::Mat result2 = cv::Mat(result1.size(), CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0,0,0));
    input1.copyTo(result2(cv::Rect(0,0,input1.cols, input1.rows)));

    result = result1.clone();

    // primitive blending, non-optimized
    for(int j=0; j<result1.rows; ++j)
        for(int i=0; i<result1.cols; ++i)
        {
            cv::Vec3b c1(0,0,0);
            cv::Vec3b c2(0,0,0);

            if(j < result1.rows && i<result1.cols) c1  = result1.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
            if(j < result2.rows && i<result2.cols) c2  = result2.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);

            bool c1_0 = false;
            bool c2_0 = false;

            if(c1 == cv::Vec3b(0,0,0)) c1_0 = true;
            if(c2 == cv::Vec3b(0,0,0)) c2_0 = true;

            cv::Vec3b color(0,0,0);

            if(!c1_0 && !c2_0)
            {
                // both nonzero: use mean value:
                color = 0.5*(c1+c2);
            }
            if(c1_0)
            {
                // c1 zero => use c2
                color = c2;
            }
            if(c2_0)
            {
                // c1 zero => use c2
                color = c1;
            }

            result.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = color;

        }


    cv::imshow("input1", input1);
    cv::imshow("input2", input2);
    cv::imshow("result", result);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/panoResult1.png", input1);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/panoResult2.png", input2);
    cv::imwrite("../outputData/panoResult.png", result);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the result with a primitive blending:

[image]

distortions come from mapping a 3D world to a 2D plane and from lens distortion. Additionally, your camera movement probably doesnt give you a perfect homography relationship between both images (only legal for planes or pure camera rotation around camera center)

Comment: Thank you for the blending code! For the warping part, in your result on the left side, you can see remnants of the input image. why is this behavior? I checked to make sure the camera is rotated around a center

Comment: I also made an edit to the question if you can provide some insight on that :)

Comment: rotating around a center must be the pinhole camera center. you should undistort your images. the blending part is very primitive and probably erroneous :D

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. I made some changes to the camera placement, undistorted the images, used automated external calibration with the chessboard and fixed the heavy parallax. Can you please advise some realtime blending algorithms? I looked into laplacian and gaussian blending but are they effective for seam blending?